# DataProcessor vs SearchKit?

Tags: searchkit, data-processor

Which one to go? Both doing the same job, SearchKit is like a favourite kid. None satisfies my small task on 100% so which one to invest the time to, per your opinion?

Comment: Can't really answer this without having some idea what the task is. Depending on what it is there might even be a third option that's better.

Comment: Frontend visual search form with actions (print pdf) and filters (participants by event title), which displays name, address and  membership types in a 3x3 grid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Demerit says, the best option for a particular task depends on the specifics.

More generally, one key difference is that SearchKit is part of core (core extension) whereas DataProcessor is a third-party extension.  SearchKit is developing rapidly and very closely linked to APIv4.  It will eventually replace much of the existing core UI and work is underway on that - see for example recent  changes to deduping and the AdminUI extension.

DataProcessor is also very capable but I don't see it ever being adopted within core.

You're asking where to invest your time: my choice is SearchKit first.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought, thank you.